# asp.net membership - how to determine programmatically is user is in role

Tags: asp.net, membership, roles

What is the code for determining if a user is in a role?

I have set up all the users through the ASP.NET Configuration Security tab but now want to put logic around some key areas so only people in certain roles can see and access these areas.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
if (User.IsInRole("rolename")) {
  // my action
}
```

Comment: User is a property of the Page and HttpContext classes, so you can access it on the page simply as User, or in non-page file as HttpContext.Current.User. More info at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Easy~

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("roleName")
```

Comment: this code will looks into the sql database (thats my provider) to determine role in asp.net?

Comment: Yes, it will look into whatever provider you have configured.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) class, specifically IsUserInRole, GetUsersInRole, AddUserToRole, etc.

I use these all the time.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to "Chris Van Opstal". i solved my problem like this way,

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "InvitationS");
        }
        return View();
    }
```